# SharePoint Online - Show/display column in default view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, csom

I am adding a site column into a document library default view and want it to be visible/shown when you click onto the list itself. However, I am unsure on how to do this. The code I have so far

```
// Get the view (this is the default view)  
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.View v = Employeecvlist.GetViewByName("All Documents");

// Load it up
clientContext.Load(v, x => x.ViewFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// Get the field I want to add to the view
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field name = 
Employeecvlist.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Name");

clientContext.Load(name);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// Add this field to the view !! Nothing else in the view object to allow to make it visible by default !!
v.ViewFields.Add(name.InternalName);

// Finally, update the view
v.Update();
```

If you look at the image file below, I basically want to be able to check the "display" checkbox to true for the above field.

[image: Edit view Screen - display columns]

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the full code, so you just need to `ExecuteQuery` after `v.Update();` to reflect the view update!

**The final code should look like**

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.View v = Employeecvlist.GetViewByName("All Documents");
// Load it up
clientContext.Load(v, x => x.ViewFields);
// Get the field I want to add to the view
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field name = 
Employeecvlist.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Name");
clientContext.Load(name);
// Add this field to the view !! Nothing else in the view object to allow to make it visible by default !!
v.ViewFields.Add(name.InternalName);
// Finally, update  the view & excute!
v.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```